# Cannot find dataSource, even though the dataSource is defined in context.xml

Tags: java, mysql, spring, datasource

I have the following bean declared for one particular dao method to use a different data source than the rest of the project.

```
    @Bean(name="kingsDataSource")
    public DataSource kingsDataSource(){

    JndiDataSourceLookup jndi = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    jndi.setResourceRef(true);

    return jndi.getDataSource("dataSource/kings");
```

Here's the use of that bean.

```
    @Resource(name="kingsDataSource")
    private DataSource ds;
```

Here's from the context.xml (omitting the user and password, which have been verified to be correct, and would have been throwing a different error if they were wrong anyway.) I have also played with putting this in the context.xml of the server, having it in one place and not the other, and having it in both places.

```
  <Resource 
  name="dataSource/kings" 
  auth="Container"
  type="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
  factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
  URL="jdbc:mysql://kings/db_netlogs" />
```

The error is a name not found exception -

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dataSource/kings] is 
not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dataSource].
```

My question, then, is - to what do I bind this and how?

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `resource-ref` declaration in `web.xml`?

Comment: I added it and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to add a `resource-ref` to your web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>dataSource/kings</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did that as well. Well, I had resource-env-ref, which I found somewhere else on SO. I'll try your code.

Comment: everything else remaining the same - this did not correct the problem. same error.